# image file size is different after base 64 encoding/decoding

Tags: java, base64, javax.imageio

I am using the following test to read a file, base 64 encode it, then decode the base 64 back to a new image.  I noticed that the new image file size (after the conversion) is significantly less than the original image leading me to think that somehow, part of the image data is being lost in the conversion. I can see the image but am worried about image quality.  Any insight on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**Test class:**

```
package test;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;

public class ImageTest {  //should be B64Test

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageTest imageTest = new ImageTest();
        try {
            BufferedImage img = null;
            BufferedImage finalImg = null;
            try {
              //  img = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/user/Desktop/test1.jpg")); 
                img = ImageIO.read(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/test1.jpg")));
                //encode base64 and print
                final String base64encoded = ImageConverter.encodeToString(img, "jpeg");
                System.out.println("read file " + base64encoded);

                //convert base64 string to image
                finalImg = ImageConverter.decodeToImage(b64encoded);
                ImageIO.write(finalImg, "jpeg", new File("/home/user/Desktop/test2.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("exception " + e);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception " + e);
        }

    }

}
```

**ImageConverter**

```
package test;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class ImageConverter {

    public static String imgToBase64String(final RenderedImage img, final String formatName) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, formatName, Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os));
            return os.toString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage base64StringToImg(final String base64String) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String)));
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
        }
    }


    public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
        String imageString = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageString;
    }


    public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
            image = ImageIO.read(bis);
            bis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

I can try testing both the base 64 encoder/decoder available in jdk8 as well as the one in sun.java.misc (which I realize I do not need to use).  Any thoughts on what might be causing the image size to shrink (I would prefer doing that myself if needed using imagemagick or graphicsmagick etc.).

The original image was 1.2 MB (1,249,934 bytes) but the new image is 354.5 kB (354,541 bytes) - width/height is the same for both images.

Comment: Why do you use ImageIO to read and write? You don't need to do that. Just read the bytes in the file, encode them and write the result to another file. And vice-versa for decoding.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for sharing.  Are you saying that's the reason for the file size to shrink or just that I should avoid it in any case?

Comment: I'm saying that this is the reason of the size shrink: instead of just encoding bytes, you're reading them as an image in memory, and then re-write that image to a file (encoding it to base64 in the process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JBNizet points out in his comment, the reason for the change in size (the size may grow as well, depending on the input image and compression settings), is that you are not just encoding/decoding binary data to/from Base64, you are also *re-encoding* the image data (two times) using JPEG encoding (with default encoding settings). Unless the original image was encoded with the exact same settings, you will lose some precision, and the file size will change.

Another likely reason for the decrease in file size, is that a `BufferedImage` does not carry any of the meta data contained in the original JPEG file. So your process of re-encoding the JPEG will also lose any Exif or XMP metadata, thumbnail, color profile etc. Depending on the source of the image, this may contribute to a significant part of the file size.

Again, as @JBNizet says, the best thing is to not involve `ImageIO` at all in this case, just use normal file I/O and encode the original bytes using Base64, and decode again to recover the original file contents exactly.

PS: If you intend on doing image processing on the image in between the Base64 encoding/decoding, you will of course need to decode the image data (using `ImageIO` or similar), but you should try to do it only once (for better performance), and perhaps look into preserving the meta data. Also, I think image encoding/decoding and Base64 encoding/decoding are separate issues, and should not be interleaved like it is now. Split it up, for a [better separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).